# Simultaneous events

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time, causality

It follows from relativity that "simultaneous events" cannot happen in our universe. If $A$ and $B$ are two events which happen at the same time in reference frame $F$, we can find reference frames $F_0$ and $F_1$ in which $A$ happens before $B$ and $B$ happens before $A$, respectively.

But what about events which are "far apart in time" in the first place?

For instance, suppose $A$ happens one year before $B$ in my reference frame $F$. Can I find a reference frame $F'$ in which $B$ happens before $A$?

Comment: Draw the picture!

Comment: @WillO - maybe he can't, since he tagged "general relativity", with Minkowski it would be easy but in this case he'd have to use Carter Penrose or Kruskal Szekeres coordinates in order to draw his 45° lines, and with his 300 reputation I'm not sure he knows how to do that.

Comment: @Yukterez :  point taken.

Comment: @WillO - nevertheless, he should indeed try to draw the diagram, if he doesn't know yet how to do it he can always [learn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSFCtskvPIM&list=PL9_n3Tqzq9iWtgD8POJFdnVUCZ_zw6OiB&index=195&t=27s) it (it isn't that [different](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMRYZMv0jRE&t=849s) to SR anyway)

Comment: You guys are real gentle men. Pretty different in comparison with MO sites, where people actually try to answer.

Answer (score 2):

> THC asked: *"suppose A happens one year before B in my reference frame F. Can I find a reference frame F′ in which B happens before A?"*

Yes, but only if A could not have influenced B (the spatial separation between A and B must be larger than 1 lightyear in your frame), so the events need a spacelike separation (flatter than 45° on the spacetime diagram, since your question is tagged with general relativity for example in [Penrose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nbsjIuWjh8&list=PLaNkJORnlhZmj0pcE8ae4yD5zpXA97Dm4&index=32&t=274s) or [Kruskal](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/46.html#plot) coordinates) in order to have a timelike observer (who is moving slower than the speed of light, so with a worldline steeper than 45° on the [diagram](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/relative.simultaneity.html)) have the order of the events reversed in his frame of reference. If it would work with timelike separated events (which it doesn't) you could break causality since action and reaction would be swapped.

Answer (score 2):

Given two events A and B, exactly one of the following is true:

1. There is a reference frame in which both events happen simultaneously.
2. There is a reference frame in which both events happen in the same spatial location, and A happens before B.
3. There is a reference frame in which both events happen in the same spatial location, and A happens after B.
4. A ray of light connects the two events.

In case 1, we say that the spacetime interval between A and B is "spacelike", in cases 2 and 3 we say it is "timelike", and in case 4 we say it is "lightlike". If the separation is timeline or lightlike, then the temporal order between the two events will be the same in every reference frame. If the separation is spacelike, then the two events will always occur in different spatial locations for every reference frame.

Moreover, there is a clear test to separate these cases, based on the sign of the spacetime interval
$$
(\Delta s)^{2}=(\Delta ct)^{2}-(\Delta x)^{2}-(\Delta y)^{2}-(\Delta z)^{2}
$$
between the two events.